# FastCGI Dynamic Server Config. for Django/Apache

Tags: django, apache, fastcgi

I'm trying to run Django 1.4 with Pyton 2.7, Flup and mod_fastcgi on Apache. So what I did was:

1. Add mod_fastcgi to httpd.conf
2. Create two files : .htaccess and index.fcgi in my public web root inside a directory called portal - `c:\xampp\htdocs\portal` - the actual Django project is in `d:\projects\portal` so inside index.fcgi I have the following:

```
#!C:/Python27/python.exe
import sys, os
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi

sys.path.append("D:/projects/portal")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "portal.settings"

runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

But when running `localhost/portal/` I get the following error in my Apache error.log

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flup\server\fcgi_base.py", line 1020, in _setupSocket
    'If you want FCGI, please create an external FCGI server '
```

It's telling me to create an external FCGI server which I could but I need it to be on a dynamic server. Any ideas?

**Update:**
My setup is on a Windows server. I can also start a Linux server so the question is more of Apache, FastCGI and adding sites witout changing any config on the server - Apache/FastCGI Server

Answer (score 1):

You did not [start your fcgi server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#starting-your-fastcgi-server).

Comment: This would start an external server. I need to start a dynamic server.

Comment: Why not use mod_wsgi ? It's way better.

Comment: I need to create a Mass Virtual Hosting enviorment in which by just adding .htaccess and index.fcgi and without the need to do anything more each website would be up and running.